# How to display the result of SQL query in unix server (putty)?

Tags: sql, unix, putty

Suppose I want to display the result of a simple SQL query, say `SELECT * FROM dual;` that is executed in SQL developer and get the result in unix server using a simple command. I do not want to use scripts to get the result. Hoping to use a single line command. I already tried using the `isql` command, but that is not working.

```
echo "select * from dual" | isql -v dbname userid hostname
```

Please help me.

Comment: That looks like Oracle. sqlplus instead of isql?

Comment: Are you suggesting . I use the command like this?

echo "select * from dual" | sqlplus -v dbname userid hostname

Comment: Close. Check the documentation for the right way to pass the arguments on the sqlplus side.

Comment: I think it is sqlplus username/password@hostname

Comment: I wasn't sure about the password but that looks right.